# Is it possible to store a function that is yet to be defined in a variable in Scala?

Tags: scala, function, variables

What I am trying to do is have a very general class for, say, items. These items would have a name and a use. They would be initialized as
`new Item("Name", function())`, e.g. `val apple = new Item("Apple", { humanObject.hunger -= 10 })`. This way they could later be retrieved from a Map, e.g. `item.Use()` which would then fire the aforementioned hunger function, or something else if it were a different item.

I feel like there's a smarter way to do this but I am not sure how.

EDIT:

I made more concrete examples. This is how `Item` can be defined:

```
class Item(val name: String, use: => Unit) {
  def Use() = use
}
```

And here is how it would be used:

```
val example = new Item("Printer", () => println("This printer seems to function!"))
```

And finally, we can fire the function somewhere else (let's forget the Map and whatnot)

```
example.Use()
This printer seems to function!
```

EDIT 2:
The problem is solved but further clarification if somebody stumbles upon this: I did not have any code originally, this was just a question that I had in my mind. The idea was to avoid inheritance so that if there were many different items you could use the same model for all of them instead of having a plethora of subclasses.

Comment: Something like `class Item(name: String, use: => Unit)`. `=>Type` means call-by-name, and when you call the function, just do `def Use() = use` without parenthesis. Alternatively you can declare it as a lambda `() => Unit` but then you need to pass the whole lambda construct when you use it like `() => {humanObject.hunger -= 10}`

Comment: Not sure what the question is.

Comment: Please update your question to include a sample of the offending code and a better description of the issue at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this on my own, thanks for the guidance texasbruce.

```
class Item(val name: String, use: => Any) {
  
  var action: () => Any = () => use

  def Use() = action()
}
```

And using it:

```
val example = new Item("Printer", println("This printer seems to function!."))
```

This can then be used as mentioned in the original post.

```
example.Use()
```

Comment: Why is `action` a `var`? In fact, why is it there at all? I don't see where it serves any purpose: `def Use = () => use`

Answer (score 1):

Seems that what you need is inheritance. I am not sure what is the use of `name` in your base class, but you can try something like this:

```
abstract class Item(name: String) {
  def use: () => Any
}

class Printer(name: String) extends Item(name) {
  override def use: () => Any = () => println(s"Printer $name seems to function!.")
}

class HumanObject {
  var hunger: Int = 100
}

class Food(name: String, humanObject: HumanObject) extends Item(name) {
  override def use: () => Any = () => humanObject.hunger -= 10
}

val example = new Printer("Printer")
example.use
val food = new Food("apple", new HumanObject())
food.use
```